# Capturing full background with camera view in 2d

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I have a small problem with my camera in 2D view. I have a background sprite that serves just as it sounds, the background. My problem is, I need the camera view to take up the entire background. At the moment I can only get the camera to capture out to the sides of the background but it will not fully catch the top and bottoms of the background.

This poses a problem, it will cause me to have to make all of my following items in the project to be super short and fat.

Yes, I know this is probably a stupid issue on my part or an easy fix, but being new to Unity, I am unaware of how to deal with this problem.

Here is a snip of my issue https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqCKT.jpg

As you can see, I cannot get the camera to reach the top and bottom of the background thus leaving me with super short and fat items.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the Viewport Rect on the editor.

[image]

You can check out [Unity3D Manual](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CamerasReference.html) for more knowledge on Cameras in Unity3D.

Comment: I have tried that. Sorry, should have noted that in the OP. When adjusting the W , H changes as well. I need to be able to individually control them.